# Was the Pantheon completely underwater when Rome flooded?

Tags: rome, flood

When in Rome, I encountered the flood markers on the side of Santa Maria sopra Minerva church.  Here is one I found online.

[image: flood marker plaque]

*[WalksInRome.com](https://www.walksinrome.com/blog/the-flood-plaques-of-the-church-of-santa-maria-sopra-minerva-rome)*

The walk of a few blocks from Santa Maria sopra Minerva to the Pantheon is slightly downhill and then the Pantheon is set down further still.  I was thinking just now that if the water was as high as the markers at Santa Maria sopra Minerva then the Pantheon would have been completely underwater.

So my question - was the Pantheon completely submerged when Rome flooded?

The "Great Flood" of the Tiber was 1557 as indicated on the marker.  Other major floods that century were in 1530 and 1598.

Comment: Seems unlikely. It's at 15m above mean sea level and 43m in height. However, it has been flooded many times according to [this article](https://www.atouchofrome.com/the_pantheon.html).

Comment: When did Rome flood?

Comment: @MCW The "Great Flood" of the Tiber was 1557 as indicted on the marker.  Other major floods that century were 1530 and 1598

Comment: Can you see the Pantheon from that marker?  If so, a simple look should tell you.  Otherwise a topographic map, maybe Google Earth or similar...

Comment: @jamesqf there are a few other possibilities: 1) The flood marker was falsified. 2) The flood marker was moved, possibly during a renovation or similar. 3) One or more of the buildings have been relocated since the flood.

Comment: Floods follow the terrain. The Elbe river bed is about 100 m above sea level in Dresden and very close to sea level in Hamburg. If there is a flood in Dresden, it does not follow that in Hamburg every building that is smaller than 100 m will be completely submerged.

Comment: But according to google street view, it seems like Santa Maria Sopra Minerva is right next (or maybe rather behind) the Pantheon, with no readily apparent differences in elevation.

Comment: @Jan that explains why the Pacific Ocean doesn't spill over into Death Valley (there are mountains in the way). It doesn't explain why the water level would be different a few blocks away in the same city.

Comment: @Jan - you are right about street view.  I can see the dome of the Pantheon from the church.   The Pantheon is big.  But the larger building is more or less in a twenty foot deep hole.

Comment: @Robert Columbia: No mountains between Dresden and Hamburg, and indeed a lot of water *does* flow from Dresden to Hamburg all the time. The reason Hamburg does not get submerged is a combination of terrain gradient and volumetric flow rate. Here is a video where the guy with the camera is actually able to film the flood from *below*, even if he does it only for a few seconds: https://youtu.be/oI1WGHqcQxI

Comment: @Wilk did they have a flood marker for 1870? https://mobile.twitter.com/romanhistory1/status/1365054599892258827

Comment: @Jan - I do not think they did.  But that is a great image.  Post an answer and you will have the green check.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Google Street View, Santa Maria sopra Minerva is actually right behind the Pantheon (with a small square in between) and the street level for both buildings seems to be quite similar. Wikipedia has an [image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Santa_Maria_sopra_Minerva,_Fassade_Hochwassermarken.jpg) by User Peter1936F that shows some more flood markers. I have marked the flood markers from 1557 and 1870 in yellow and red, respectively. Judging again from google street view, the height difference between the two markers seems to be about one and a half meter.

[image: Flood markers at Santa Maria sopra Minerva, markers for 1557 and 1870 are marked]

Why 1870? Because for the 1870 flood there are actually photographs of the flooded Pantheon, e.g. [here](https://mobile.twitter.com/romanhistory1/status/1365054599892258827?lang=en).

Comment: So the answer to the question is no, it wasn't completely submerged.